# What does a schema.conf for Test::DBIx::Class look like?

Tags: perl, testing, dbix-class

The SYNOPSIS for [Test::DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aDBIx%3a%3aClass) states:

> Yes, it looks like a lot of boilerplate, but sensible defaults are in place 
>   (the above code example shows most of the existing defaults) and 
>   configuration data can be loaded from a central file. So your 'real life' 
>   example is going to look closer to (assuming you put all your test 
>   configuration in the standard place, "t/etc/schema.conf":

Other than this, I can't seem to find a reference to t/etc/schema.conf or even an example of what it might look like.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the t(est) directory for an example.
It uses Config::Any to load the file so you can use the config file format of your choice.
Doc patch welcome to clarify this!

Comment: You mean [this](https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/Test-DBIx-Class-0.34/t/etc/example/schema.pl)? It doesn't even have any connection info.

Comment: Thanks for this. I now see that there is more info in the "CONFIGURATION BY FILE" section.  I do think a doc patch is in order here, though.  I'll see what I can do.  To echo @ikegami, that schema.pl in the dist is pretty bare-bones. :)